# Read multiple files, dictionary value gets overwritten

Tags: python, pandas

When I was reading multiple files and exporting it, I realised that the values on these 4 column got overwritten by the latest value. Every file has the same iat cell location. I will like to know if this can be looped and values not getting overwritten.

```
name = df.iat[1,1]
age = df.iat[2,1]
height = df.iat[2,2]
address = df.iat[2,3]

Details = {'Name':name, 'Age':age,'Height':height,'Address':address}
df1 = pd.Series(Details).to_Frame()
df1 = df1.T
```

For example, 
(1st Data):
Name: John
Age: 20
Height: 1.7m
Address: Bla Bla Bla

(2nd Data):
Name: Jack
Age: 21
Height: 1.7m
Address: Blah Blah Blah

(3rd Data):
Name: Jane
Age: 20
Height: 1.62m
Address: Blah Blah

Answer (score 0):

You can loop and append your values to list.

```
name, age, height, address = [], [], [], []

for df in dfs:
    name.append(df.iat[1,1])
    age.append(df.iat[2,1])
    height.append(df.iat[2,2])
    address.append(df.iat[2,3])

    Details = {'Name':name, 'Age':age,'Height':height,'Address':address}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Details)
```

Comment: is it possible to do df['Name']= []?

Comment: No it is not, it can not be empty but it can be `df['Name'] = [np.nan]`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `df['Name']= []?`

Comment: To loop the list

Comment: I thought you read multiple files and dfs are the dataframes that contains your files and a df is one file.

Comment: my df is concat